# Xubuntu 12.10: Possible to use animated gifs as a background?

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, xfce, desktop-background

I really, really want to use
http://www.reddit.com/r/cinemagraphs

I've done a lot of research on this, but the answers seem to vary greatly and I haven't had much success with any of the other suggestions, and I can't find any answers on xubuntu 12.10, only earlier versions of xubuntu (not many), but mostly just ubuntu.

I feel these gifs would be perfect for a background (though they are a bit low-res, good enough for now)

Also, I do run dual monitors, so if something can be tailored to that fact (but def not required, any info will do), I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: Adding what you have tried would help people not telling what you have already done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I don't know whether you have tried the following suggestions, as you haven't responded to the comment, but I thought I would mention the following ways, which are about the only options available.)

---

**General Introduction**

Without using compiz or some special compositor plugin, what you can do on Xubuntu is use `xwinwrap`; even though the program hasn't been updated officially for a while, there is an improved version available [here](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/resources/downloads/shantz-xwinwrap.zip) with many comments posted by users.

However, you may want to use the excellent [gwinwrap](https://code.google.com/p/gwinwrap/), which is a front-end to `xwinwrap`. You must install it by following the [instructions from the official site](https://code.google.com/p/gwinwrap/wiki/SubversionInstallation); it is, however, very quick and easy. You also need `mplayer` and `xscreensaver` installed in addition to `xwinwrap`.  Even though the documentation keeps mentioning screensavers, it does work for the desktop as well, as this [useful youtube video demonstrates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1LhcawnR8g), and this is one way to make a desktop 'active'.

So, you could either use `xwinwrap` as it is and [follow the tutorial here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=926519) so that you can display your gif, or it may be easier to use `gwinwrap`. You could simply convert your gif to a video file and select it in `gwinwrap` and it would loop as the desktop background. Other options such as the size of the video could be passed to mplayer in the `gwinwrap` options.

If you run `gwinwrap` from terminal and select various settings and then apply them, you can see the `xwinwrap` command lines being used. As an example, `gwinwrap` executes an `xwinwrap` command (in conjunction with `mplayer`) such as this:

```
nice -n 15 xwinwrap -s -st -sp -b -ni -fs -nf -ov -o 1.000000 -- mplayer /home/mike/jazz.mp4 -quiet -noconsolecontrols -loop 0 -wid WID
```

(To kill any `xwinwrap` actions which have gone awry, open a terminal and run `killall xwinwrap`.)

**Specific instructions**

1) Choose your animated gif from your collections and convert it to a video format such as mp4 or avi; you can do this directly with `ffmpeg`, as noted in the suggestions from [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/5730/how-do-i-convert-an-animated-gif-to-a-youtube-friendly-video-format). If the quality isn't what you expected, try the other alternatives.

2) Start `gwinwrap`, click 'new' on the first screen, and then on the second, add your video of your converted gif, specify any settings and click apply (see screenshot below).

Note: you usually have to have window compositing enabled in XFCE settings > window manager tweaks. As noted in some of the comments for [xwinwrap](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2008/09/03/shantz-xwinwrap.html), sometimes the video may overlay other windows depending on your graphics card. It should not happen, however, and using xwinwrap/gwinwrap is about the best way to achieve what you want.

[image]

Comment: I tried the method you mentioned, but i'm not able to get it to work: executing `gwinwrapper.py` does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

`xwinwrap` seems like the way to go as [this answer explains](https://askubuntu.com/a/260355/527764).

However, I couldn't get it working, so created something similar. It's basic, but does the job, you can find it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/csucu/giphytool).

#### Installation

Download a release from [here](https://github.com/csucu/giphytool/releases), then extract/unzip, enter the directory, and run

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

#### Usage

- To set a gif in the center of the screen

  ```
  giphytool -c /path/to/animation.gif
  ```
- For full usage guidance

  ```
  giphytool --help
  ```

Comment: Holy cow, I've just recently come back to this question again and found this post (I also couldn't get xwinwrap to work, either). So my question is - what OSes does this work for? Any(most) debian systems? I ask because sometimes this wallpaper crap is very specific to certain distros - is this the case here? I'm on a windows machine right now, I will test this asap later today.

Comment: It should work on most Linux distributions i think, it just requires GTK-3. But I've only tested this on Xubuntu 16.04 so far. I'll test this on a few others soon.

Comment: @Cey 3 years later (on Ubuntu 18.04) it doesn't work. If you are still maintaining it, let me know and I'll open an issue.

Comment: @Ælex sure, open an issue and i'll take a look at it